# What is the syntax for Single Abstract Method with generic types in a trait

Tags: scala

Say I define a class with ordering as below:

```
case class C(i: Int)

implicit def ordering[A <: C]: Ordering[A] = new Ordering[A] {
    def compare(c1: A, c2: A): Int = c1.i.compareTo(c2.i)
}
```

I get the following info from the compiler:

> Convert expression to Single Abstract Method less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   Inspection info: Checks if an expression can be converted to SAM
>   (Single Abstract Method). 
>   Before: new Thread(new Runnable {
>       override def run() = println() }
>   After: new Thread(() => println())

But it is not obvious to me what the correct syntax in this case is? I have tried the code below but it does not compile:

```
implicit def ordering[A <: C]: Ordering[A] = new Ordering[A]((c1: A, c2: A) => c1.i.compareTo(c2.i))
```

Comment: Note that in the example there's no `new Runnable` after conversion, similarly you should have no `new Ordering`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
 implicit def ordering[A <: C]: Ordering[A] = (c1: A, c2: A) => c1.i.compareTo(c2.i)
```

Single Abstract Methods are used when you create an instance of a trait with one and only one method.

[SAM](https://herringtondarkholme.github.io/2015/01/24/scala-sam/) comes from java8, and were introduced in scala 2.12: